# Is Monero compatible with Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: monerod, linux, windows

I built monerod from github source.

coretests and unit_tests failed

monerod —dB-salvage

"Attempts to get hash from heigh 0 failed. - - hash not in db"

Before doing this I downloaded Linux, 64-bit from Getmonero.org which also aborted.

Is monerod compatible with WSL ?

Answer (score 1):

Monero has *native* support for Windows, so I doubt any of the developers would want to waste time trying to support WSL (and there are no developers I'm aware of that are interested in working on this).

Running Monero natively on Windows is always going to have far better performance than running through something like WSL.

There is one aspect that is mentioned in the [README](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/README.md) however, and that is the `depends` build system, which produces reproducible builds:

> Using depends might also be easier to compile Monero on Windows than
>   using MSYS. Activate Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) with a distro
>   (for example Ubuntu), install the apt build-essentials and follow the
>   depends steps as depicted above.

Worth taking note of the word "might" from the above quote and also that the Monero releases do not currently use the `depends` builds (though hopefully will soon).